# jquery get form id by input id

Tags: jquery, forms

I have really basic question.
How can I get form id by input element id.

```
<form id="my_form">
    <fieldset>
        <!--some <div>'s-->
            <input id="my_input"></div>
        <!--some <div>'s end-->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now if I have

```
var form_input = $('#my_input');
```

How can I get id "my_form"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). It searches up the ancestors* of an element to find the first (closest) match.

```
$('#my_input').closest('form').attr('id');
```

`*`*Note: closest() searches upwards starting with the current element, therefore it can match the current element.*

Answer (score 9):

You don't even need jQuery for this. Every form element has a .form attribute you can use to directly access the form object without needing jQuery's iterative search:

```
$('#my_input').get(0).form.id
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method is to use `closest()`:

```
var id = $('#my_input').closest('form').attr('id');
```